# AWS Elastic Beanstalk App (ASP.NET Core MVC) is failing to call external API

Tags: .net-core, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, httpclient

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have a need to call an external API from the application to send SMS. It all works very well in localhost and got the message as well, but when I deploy the changes to elastic beanstalk, this external API call to send SMS times out.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<SMSResponse> SendSMS(KeyValuePair<string, string>[] keys)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUrl);
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keys);
        var result = await client.PostAsync("api/send.json", content);
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var res = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SMSResponse>(resultContent);
        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new SMSResponse() { status = "fail", exception = ex };
    }
}
```

What I understood is AWS is blocking the external outbound calls. In my initial research I've found we can create NAT gateway to allow external API calls from AWS.

Please help to achieve this. Thanks